# Map<Long, Entity>, how to make the map key referenced an Entity Id?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have 3 entities: Company, Developer and CompanyDeveloperRoles.

In my Developer class I have a map :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_developer")
private Map<Long, CompanyDeveloperRoles> companyRoles;
```

Jpa created 3 classes

```
Company (company_id, company_name, etc)
Developer (developer_id, developer_name, etc)
company_developer_roles(id, fk_developer, company_roles_key)
```

[image]

How can I do to make my `company_roles_key` a foreign key of company `id`? 
For the moment there is no relation between the key of the map and the company. I want the key of the map the foreign key of the id of the company.

My class CompanyDeveloperRoles looks like :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = GaraRolesEnum.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "developer_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@Column(name = "dev_role", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<GaraRolesEnum> userRoles;
```

Could you help me, please ?

Answer (score 3):

You use the `@MapKey` for that for that:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_developer")
@MapKey(name="companyRolesKey")
private Map<Long, CompanyDeveloperRoles> companyRoles;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I add ```@Mapkey(name="company_roles_key")````, I have this error :  `Map key property not found: com.gara.bo.model.CompanyDeveloperRoles.company_roles_key`. I think, it because company_roles_key is created during the generation of classes ? I updated my initial post to add the content of CompanyDeveloperRoles.

Comment: Maybe should I declare company_roles_key in CompanyDeveloperRoles ?

Comment: It uses the field name on the entity. So sth like companyRolesKey. Not the db column name

Comment: jpa can't found the property companyRolesKey. I got this new error : `Map key property not found: com.gara.bo.model.CompanyDeveloperRoles.companyRolesKey`

Comment: Do you have it defined

Comment: in the class companyDeveloperRoles  ? no.

Comment: You should then

Comment: I added `private Company companyRolesKey;` in the class. I succeeded to run the app but I dont have the foreign key. I added the annotation @ManyToOne on se variable but got a spring error.